# How to change the same code stored in several places after I improve one of them?

Tags: version-control, code-reuse, matlab

I have some code written in Matlab. I use the code in different folders which contains different data. Because I want to change some parameters for each different data, I keep the code in the folder of each data to remember what parameters I have used.

The problem is that sometimes I improve the code and it is hard to go to each folder and change that part of code. Is there any solution to this problem? It would be good if I change some part of the code then it changes in all other places I have stored the same code.

Would version control help with this problem?

Comment: @fileunderwater: IMHO it fits both sites. Version control (VC) is such an essential part of software development, that StackOverflow fits as well as the other site. If you will search the SO site, you will find tons of VC-related questions and answers.

Comment: I am interested mostly in the experience of other researcher who had the similar problem rather than asking for a software. I would like to know what other researcher has done.

Answer (score 8):

Version control is not the issue here. It's a fundamental principle of programming that says "Don't repeat yourself". It's a time-honored maxim, largely for exactly the reason you cite.

If at all possible, arrange things so that the logic you write lives in **one** place and one place only. I know nothing about Matlab, so I have no diea whether it's possible to include code from another file, cal subroutines, etc., but it's worth finding out.

If it definitely isn't possible to refactor your code to obey DRY, the next biggest principle applies: "Don't write code. Write programs that write code." In other words, write a tiny shell script/Perl app/whatever you like that generates all the variants of this code at once. Then, the next time you change something you only have to change it in the helper script. (You do have to remember to re-run the helper script - that's the price you pay for using a tool that doesn't allow you to practice proper DRYness.)

Comment: Matlab has `run(scriptname)` so you can certainly source code from other scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Version control isn't what you need here. You need to put your code which lives in many places in a single place.

A good first step would be to create a folder for your shared code, copy the shared code into functions in that shared folders, and replace the original copies with function calls to the code in the shared folder.

Here is the documentation to get you started with authoring functions:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html

For the original files to be able to find the new functions in the new shared folder, you'll need to add that new folder to your MATLAB search path. more information is here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/search-path.html